# Stop Drupal Commerce automatically adding hyphens before product variations radio button labels

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, commerce

Using Drupal Commerce I have created product variations with attributes that correspond to my taxonomies. When I use radio buttons to allow the user to select a specific variation Drupal Commerce adds a hyphen to the start the radio button label. For example my taxonomy term is 'White gold' but the radio button label that is displayed is '-White gold'.

How do I stop these hyphens from being added?

[image: Screenshot of hyphens before radio button labels]

Answer (score 1):

These hyphens are not being added by Drupal Commerce itself, so you'll need to look into what other modules on the site might be interacting with the form.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably an effect of the use of nested taxonomy terms there. In particular the function

[`taxonomy_allowed_values`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_allowed_values/7)

```
/**
 * Returns the set of valid terms for a taxonomy field.
 *
 * @param $field
 *   The field definition.
 * @return
 *   The array of valid terms for this field, keyed by term id.
 */
function taxonomy_allowed_values($field) {
  $options = array();
  foreach ($field['settings']['allowed_values'] as $tree) {
    if ($vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load($tree['vocabulary'])) {
      if ($terms = taxonomy_get_tree($vocabulary->vid, $tree['parent'])) {
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
          $options[$term->tid] = str_repeat('-', $term->depth) . $term->name;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return $options;
}
```

This part here:

```
$options[$term->tid] = str_repeat('-', $term->depth) . $term->name;
```

Adds a hyphen prefix to the term based on the term depth in the vocabulary.

It's called by [`taxonomy_options_list`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_options_list/7)

You could actually add your own `option_list` function by adding this to the term_reference field settings:

```
$field['settings']['options_list_callback'] = 'my_module_taxonomy_options_list';
```

Alternatively you may be able to `form_alter` them out from display with

```
hook_form_commerce_add_to_cart_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state);
```

Comment: Thanks David Thomas, you clearly explain what the problem is, and suggest some starting points that look very helpful. Yes, I am using nested taxonomy terms. I tried to start using your second suggestion, but I am quite new to customising Drupal. As a test of whether the hook was being called, in my template.php I added `function hook_form_commerce_add_to_cart_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_set_message(t("Add to cart being shown"), 'status');
}` The message does not show when I go to my product page. I have tried clearing my cache. Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?